# how to call a bash function providing environment variables stored in a Bash array?

Tags: bash

I got two variables in a bash script. One contains the name of a function within the script while the other one is an array containing `KEY=VALUE` or `KEY='VALUE WITH SPACES'` pairs. They are the result of parsing a specific file, and I can't change this.

What I want to do is to invoke the function whose name I got. This is quite simple:

```
# get the value for the function
myfunc="some_function"
# invoke the function whose name is stored in $myfunc
$myfunc
```

Consider the function `foo` be defined as

```
function foo
{
   echo "MYVAR: $MYVAR"
   echo "MYVAR2: $MYVAR2" 
}
```

If I get the variables

```
funcname="foo"
declare -a funcenv=(MYVAR=test "MYVAR2='test2 test3'")
```

How would I use them to call `foo` with the pairs of `funcenv` being added to the environment? A (non-variable) invocation would look like

```
MYVAR=test MYVAR2='tes2 test3' foo
```

I tried to script it like

```
"${funcenv[@]}" "$funcname"
```

But this leads to an error (`MYVAR=test: command not found`).

How do I properly call the function with the arguments of the array put in its environment (I do not want to export them, they should just be available for the invoked function)?

Comment: You need to use `eval` to execute code that you're constructing dynamically.

Comment: The fact that you will need `eval` to do this should be considered a major design flaw in your system, and that should be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
declare -a funcenv=(MYVAR=test "MYVAR2='test2 test3'")
for pairs in "${funcenv[@]}"; do
    eval "$pairs"
done
"$funcname"
```

Note however that the variables will be visible outside the function too.
If you want to avoid that, then you can wrap all the above in a `(...)` subshell.

Comment: Using `declare` might be safer than using `eval`. If nothing else, it documents that you are defining variables, not executing arbitrary code. (Although that would require you use `MYVAR2=test2 test3` without single quotes in the array.)

Comment: @chepner I think the evil `eval` is needed to evaluate the expression, because it may have embedded quoting. (OP said the array content is given, not possible to change)

Comment: @janos Yeah, I realized that after I first commented, added the parenthetical to address that. Ideally, and I know the OP said they couldn't change it, the configuration *would* change, because a configuration system relying on `eval` is fragile at best.

Comment: @chepner I could replace the single quotes with double quotes after parsing, if this would help (or is it about quotes at all?). How could an `eval`-less solution look like then?

Comment: Compare `eval "foo='1 2'"` and `declare "foo=1 2"`; both declare `foo` to have a value of `1 2`. Leave the quotes out of `eval`, and you get an error trying to run a command named `2` with `foo=1` in its environment. *Add* the quotes to `declare`, and the quotes are part of the value of `foo`. There isn't really a way to accommodate both; they simply behave differently.

Comment: The benefit of `declare` over `eval` can be seen by comparing, for example, `eval 'foo=$(echo hi)'` and `declare 'foo=$(echo hi)'`. `eval` executes the command substitution; `declare` does not.

Comment: @chepner ah ok, now I get the point, thank you! Maybe I can get the input to be spaceless and could get rid of the `eval` that way

Comment: Much simpler would be to make your the other file a script in its own right, then simply source it.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you pass them as arguments to your function?

```
function f() { echo "first: $1";  echo "second: $2"; }

fn=f; $fn oneword "two words"
```

Comment: because I do already pass arguments to it (left it out for the sake of simplicity), and I do need to differ between arguments and the "second kind of arguments", and need some kind of hashes as well, which both would environment variables provide